# Spring MVC pass model to view then to controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm stuck with my code, I'm trying to pass the info of the object "Student". My scenario is like this:

1. Registration Form (fill the details then press submit button go to next page)
2. From this view the model will be printed out then press the next button again.
3. This third page will just show the information again.

**Q: How can i pass the same object and display it to other views?**

My code is like this.

**Registration view:**

```
<form action="/HamburgerProject/stuSubmitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>          <td><input type="text" name="studentName"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age:</td>           <td><input type="text" name="studentAge"></td></tr>
    <tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit this">
</form>
```

**First Information View:**

```
<form action="/HamburgerProject/stuSubmitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Student's Name :</td>
        <td>${student.studentName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Student's Age :</td>
        <td>${student.studentAge}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

**Second Information View:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Student's Name :</td>
        <td>${student.studentName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Student's Age :</td>
        <td>${student.studentAge}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/stuAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getStudentAdmissionForm() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value="/stuSubmitAdmissionForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView submitModelAttributeAnnotationAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/stuDisplayForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView getStudent(Student student) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("NewForm");
    model.addObject(student);

    return  model;
}
```

In attempting to re-display the information from second view to third view the object Student is not being passed.

Comment: what do the second method? Are missing here to pass the `student` object to the `model` object?

Comment: Hi Manu, The second method is the one who fetch the Student object from the registration form, and  then display it on the second information view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no fields to submit in your fist information view. You have to add the values to hidden fileds:

```
<form action="/HamburgerProject/stuSubmitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Student's Name :</td>
        <td>${student.studentName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Student's Age :</td>
        <td>${student.studentAge}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="hidden" name="studentName" value="${student.studentName}">
    <input type="hidden" name="studentAge" value="${student.studentAge}">
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello Jens, thank you for your answer, just a quick note, does that mean that once the object has been passed to the view its gone already? Thank you in advance for your consideration, this is my first attempt to do a web application, not much of a programmer. TIA.

Comment: @sdcz6 Yes the model vill be created from the values wich are send from the form.

Comment: Hi Jens, great it did work.. Hmm but the downside here is that if i have lots attribute then i need to re-submit each field right? Can singleton avoid all the re-assignment of the properties?

Comment: @sdcz6 No you have to resubmit all the properties :(